# VB.NET - Problem with transparent background PNG and ImageSharp quantizer

Tags: vb.net, imagesharp

I am trying to make a WinForms app in VB.NET (Framework 4.7.2) that optimizes an electronic signature using ImageSharp, and I am running into a problem.  When I try to use the OctreeQuantizer to decrease the number of colors in the PNG, I get an inverted / negative image if the source has a transparent background.  This is a problem since the signature will need to be transparent when it is applied to a document.

[Application Window - Top is original signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofPKj.png)

[Original Save Dialog from Paint.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEQfS.png)

As you can see, I saved the original image as an 8bpp PNG with transparency using Paint.NET

Here's my quantize function:

```
    Public Shared Function QuantizeImageGrayscalePNG(ByVal vstrSource As String, ByVal vintMaxColors As Integer) As Bitmap
        Dim poqQuant As New OctreeQuantizer()
        Dim pencPNG As New PngEncoder() With {.BitDepth = PngBitDepth.Bit8, .ColorType = PngColorType.GrayscaleWithAlpha}

        vintMaxColors = Math.Min(256, vintMaxColors)
        If vstrSource IsNot Nothing AndAlso IO.File.Exists(vstrSource) AndAlso vintMaxColors > 0 Then
            Using piNew As Image = Image.Load(vstrSource),
                  pstOutput As New IO.MemoryStream()

                poqQuant.Options.MaxColors = vintMaxColors

                piNew.Mutate(Sub(x) x.Quantize(poqQuant))
                piNew.Save(pstOutput, pencPNG)

                Return Bitmap.FromStream(pstOutput)
            End Using
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

If I use an image with no transparency as the source, the issue does not occur.  I also tried commenting out the Mutate function, and it "works" but of course does not change the number of colors or image size.

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from JimBobSquarePants on GitHub:

> Octree only supports a single transparent color . For Png you need to use the Wu quantizer which is the default quantizer.
>
> However, if you are trying to reduce the colors in a png you should be saving it in indexed format by setting the PngColorType in the encoder along with a custom Wu quantizer with your max color count.

Not sure that is a full answer, but my issue was closed so that's all I'm getting.

Comment: It’s the full answer